# Is it possible to comment out a specific script via JS?

Tags: javascript, comments

I'm new to JS, can anyone help?

IE throws errors in some scripts. Therefore, I want to check if this is IE, then enclose the script in a comment, if not, then uncomment.

```
<script data-name="notIE" scr="js/ourScript.js"></script>
```

```
if(/*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode){

 document.querySelector('script[data-name="myscript"]').createComment();//What should I do?

}else{ 
 
if comment exist some how remove it

}
```

P.S. Or are there any alternatives for conditional comments. They don't work in IE 11 anymore, do they?

Comment: After a script is executed there is no way back. You cannot 'unexecute' it.

Comment: No, you can't alter files when they are rendered. However you can *add* scripts whenever a condition is true using JavaScript.

Comment: I can of course go the easier way and use php for this. But I'm not sure how efficient and productive it is.

Comment: You can use something like Babel to transform your JavaScript into code that IE will accept, or you can conditionally *load* an entire script that involves non-IE features. Or you can manually avoid using non-IE features of course.

Comment: I used Babel, and IE still gave some errors.
 There were previously conditional comments. Are there any alternatives to them for IE 10 and IE 11?

Comment: @Hi_TecH Unfortunately not. Either use PHP to detect the user-agent or Feature Detection in JavaScript to determine what the browser is and supports.